# Dynamically spawn/cancel threads to handle varying load

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

Here's a situation.

Multiple TCP requests coming from clients. Request load varies.

Currently server side threadpool instantiates fixed number of threads at program initialization.
What will be good strategy to dynamically spawn/cancel threads in a threadpool?

Comment: The whole point of a threadpool is that you DON'T "dynamically spawn/cancel threads "

Comment: Not doing it at all is a good strategy.

Comment: @MitchWheat Please see my comment in David Schwartz answer. Doesn't it a legit reason even if I'm using threadpool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no point. You don't need more threads to do more work. Just create a few more threads than the number of things you can usefully do at once and leave it at that.

Comment: So you're suggesting that if I get 100 concurrent requests in peak load, I should spawn at least 100 threads at program init. But what if my average load is 10 concurrent requests. Won't be 100 threads look like resource misuse?

Comment: @DivyangPatel: No, spawn one thread per CPU, plus a few more in case some of them have to block for some reason. The number of CPUs determines the number of things you can usefully do at once. Hopefully, your threadpool already handles this for you.

Comment: @David That's quite useful cue. But do you have any useful analysis or link which can provide a matrix, which can show relations between number of requests, workload per request and number of threads to spawn. That will be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: Number of requests doesn't matter.  Look at number of cores (or number of hyperthreads) in your system.  Multiply by ratio of (average total time it takes to perform a request / average amount of cpu time used per request).  Multiply by another factor of 2 for good luck.  Any more threads than that and you are just wasting time in thread scheduling without improving your ability to handle peak load.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to handle a thread-pool, is to have a vector of threads, and for each thread have a queue of [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) objects. The threads simply pops a function from its queue, and executes it.

You don't have to spawn/cancel threads as they already are running, created when the thread-pool is created. While the threads don't do any work, they either wait for a signal telling it that there is functions in its queue, or poll the queue with sleeps in between.

Comment: That's what I'm doing with my threadpool. Please see my comment to David Schwartz's answer about resource misuse of idle threads.

Comment: @DivyangPatel If you use some kind of signaling instead of polling (like e.g. [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)), then the resource usage is minimal. First of all the thread won't use any CPU cycles, second the memory used by sleeping thread is negligible.

Comment: Yes I'm using condition_variable for signaling of request item in queue to threadpool.